# Is there a limit on a JS variable that holds the contents of a file that is returned from ReadAll method?

Tags: javascript

I am reading a file using JS like this:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var s = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\\file.txt", 1, true);
rows = s.ReadAll(); //also we can use s.ReadAll() to read all the lines;
s.Close();
```

Is there a limit to the variable 'rows'? If I have a file with 1 million rows, will that be okay, or could it exceed the memory capacity of the variable?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you reading that file? Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MS docs:

> For large files, using the ReadAll method wastes memory resources. Other techniques should be used to input a file, such as reading a file line by line.

Try [ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7se9d4f%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method.
For example,

```
var ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8;

var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

// Open the file for output.
var filename = "c:\\testfile.txt";

var f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename, ForWriting, true);

// Write to the file.
f.WriteLine("Hello world!");
f.WriteLine("The quick brown fox");
f.Close();

// Open the file for input.
f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename, ForReading);

// Read from the file and display the results.
while (!f.AtEndOfStream)
    {
    var r = f.ReadLine();
    document.write (r + "<br />");
    }
f.Close();
```

Comment: Right, but is there a maximum limit on the memory storage for that variable?

Comment: Limits are settled by OS and free space of virtual memory. So it's a system specific.